# java - pdfbox text location and encoding troubles

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, fonts, pdfbox

Good time!
I need to extract text from pdf, highlight some words and write It back.
I wrote wrapper around PDFTextStriiper for making method `getCharactersByArticle()` public.
And I met 2 troubles.
1) Coordinates. The Y coordinat which I'm getting from reading file is reversed. And if I make

```
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(position.getX(), position.getY());
contentStream.drawString(position.getCharacter());
```

lines from bottom are printed in the top of result pdf, and lines from the top of previous pdf are printed at the bottom.

2) Encoding. The text extrated correctly. But it prints incorrectly. I need to work with cyrillic pdf's so, does smb knows, how to extract font and encoding correctly.

```
contentStream.setFont(position.getFont(), position.getFontSize());
```

doesn't work properly.

Somebody help me, please!

Comment: *lines from the top of previous pdf are printed at the bottom.* - I don't understand what you mean here: Do you parse multiple pdfs and have left-overs from a previous document in a new one? Concerning *The text extrated correctly. But it prints incorrectly.* though, `contentStream.drawString` does not take the font encoding into account and always assumes either **ISO-8859-1** or **UTF-16BE**, the former one not being cyrillic-friendly and the latter one completely inadequate. Essentially you have to write your own `drawString` replacement which uses the actual encoding of the font.

Comment: What do you mean by "Y coordinate is reversed"? You realise coordinates in a PDF document are measured with the origin in the lower left corner of the page, right?

Comment: But how cn I write own DrawString with correct encoding if I don't know how to extract encoding? `position.getFont().getEncoding()` returns `null`.

Comment: About coordianates. For exmaple, I have pdf with one simple in toop right corner. When I'm getting it's position if I print it by the code above it will be printed to the bottom right corner.

Comment: *But how cn I write own DrawString with correct encoding if I don't know how to extract encoding?* - You cannot. *`position.getFont().getEncoding()` returns `null`* - That may be a shortcoming of PDFBox or the PDF does not contain the required information. Can you share the document?